# KeyboardState and Layout

Tags: c#, windows, input, keyboard, interop

I am getting the Keyboard State using interop in c#

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);
```

My problem is that apparently when I switch keyboardLayout (i.e. from QWERTY to Dvorak with <kbd>Ctrl-Shift</kbd>) the function `GetKeyboardState` returns different virtual key codes. Is there a way to simply get the key-codes according to the layout the actual keyboard manufacturer used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to map the virtual key codes to keyboard scan codes. See [MapVirtualKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: uh, so I guess I map from the key codes I got using GetKeyboardState to the scan code, using the current keyboard layout (whatever that may be) and then I map from the scan code using the QWERTY keyboard layout to the get the desired key code?
Is there a way to get the scan codes directly?

Comment: I don't know of any way to get the scan codes directly without writing a keyboard hook. You could eliminate the mapping from scan code to QWERTY by coding your program to check agains the scan codes rather than the QWERTY virtual keys. Or, you could create the scancode-to-QWERTY mapping as a lookup table in your program. Just pre-create it at program startup.

Comment: ah, I'll have to capture WM_KEYDOWN messages and extract the scan code from there....